How to match {0} but allowing proper escape?
I want to create a simple text templating that allow defining placeholders using {0}, similar to what .Net does using string.format method.
Basically I want this:
      format("{0}", 42), // output `42`
      format("{0} {1}", 42, "bar"), // output `42 bar`
      format("{1} {1}", 42, "bar"), // output `bar bar` ({0} ignored)
      format("{{0", 42), // output `{0` (`{{` is an escaped `{`)
      format("{{{0}", 42), // output `{42` : an escaped brace and the formatted value
      format("Mix {{0}} and {0}", 42), // outputs `Mix {0} and 42`
      format("Invalid closing brace }"), // should fail, since the closing brace does close an opening one
      format("Invalid placeholder {z}"), // should fail, not an integer
      format("{0}", "With { in value"), // output `With { in value`, inner { should be broke the format

I'm trying to play with regex and backtracking to deal with the escaped braces.


 function format(template: string, ...values: unknown[]): string {
      const regex = /(?!({{)+){(\d+)}(?<!(}}))/gm;
      return template.replace(regex, ([, index]) => {
        const valueIndex = parseInt(index, 10);
        if (valueIndex >= values.length) throw new Error("Not enough arguments")
        return String(values[valueIndex]);

      });
    }

    console.log([
      format("{0}", 42), // output `42`
      format("{0} {1}", 42, "bar"), // output `42 bar`
      format("{1} {1}", 42, "bar"), // output `bar bar` ({0} ignored)
      format("{{0", 42), // output `{0` (`{{` is an escaped `{`)
      format("{{{0}", 42), // output `{42` : an escaped brace and the formatted value
      format("Mix {{0}} and {0}", 42), // outputs `Mix {0} and 42`
      format("Invalid closing brace }"), // should fail, since the closing brace does not close an opening one
      format("Invalid placeholder {z}"), // should fail, not an integer
      format("{0}", "With { in value"), // output `With { in value`, inner { should be broke the format
    ]);

    try {
      format("{0} {1}", 42); // throw error because not enough argument are passed
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }



However, I'm struggling to properly replaced the escaped braces by a single brace
How to fix it ?

What should happen with {0}}?

it should fail. Only double {{ and }} are allowed if not a placeholder

Should it fail in the sense that it should raise an error? Or should it just not match and replace it? But then replace the }} with a single one...?

should throw. If not, incorrect templates will leak

OK, then maybe this is should be mentioned in the question with a test case for it. Still I think this behaviour is unbalanced, because you wouldn't throw for the mirrored case {{0}. Wouldn't it be more elegant if it was the same behaviour?

Update the question to clarify. {{0} should also fail

OK, I think I understood the expected logic. Let me know if I interpreted it wrong.

I would suggest replacing the double braces in the same replace call. For catching the "syntax" errors, I would suggest that when only a single brace is found as left-over (after potentially replacing pairs of them), that couldn't combine with a place holder, to throw it as a syntax error:


function format(template, ...values) {
  const regex = /{(\d+)}|([{}])(\2?)/g;
  return template.replace(regex, (_, index, brace, escaped) => {
    if (escaped) return brace;
    if (brace) throw new Error("Unescaped literal brace");
    if (+index >= values.length) throw new Error("Not enough arguments");
    return values[+index];
  });
}


const tests = [
  ["{0}", 42], // output `42`
  ["{0} {1}", 42, "bar"], // output `42 bar`
  ["{1} {1}", 42, "bar"], // output `bar bar` ({0} ignored)
  ["{{0", 42], // output `{0` (`{{` is an escaped `{`)
  ["{{{0}", 42], // output `{42` : an escaped brace and the formatted value
  ["Mix {{0}} and {0}", 42], // outputs `Mix {0} and 42`
  ["Invalid closing brace }"], // should fail, since the closing brace does not close an opening one
  ["Invalid placeholder {z}"], // should fail, not an integer
  ["{0}", "With { in value"], // output `With { in value`, inner { should be broke the format
  ["{0} {1}", 42], // throw error because not enough argument are passed
];

for (const [test, ...args] of tests) {
  try {
    console.log(format(test, ...args));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error:", e.message);
  }
}



There is no need for look-around assertions as there is no risk that in backtracking these paired braces get chunked up in the wrong way.
The \2 backreference serves to indicate that a double of the brace was matched, indicating an escaped brace (either { or }). The ? is greedy, but if there is no such duplicate brace, we have captured a single brace that violates the syntax.

Updated my answer in light of the update to the question that indicates an error should be thrown if braces are not escaped when they actually should be.

awesome. Thanks !

You can use
(?<=(?<!\{)(?:\{\{)*)\{\d+}(?!(?:}})*}(?!}))

See the regex demo.
Details:

(?<=(?<!\{)(?:\{\{)*)\{ - a { char that is not escaped (there must not be a { followed with zero or more double { chars)
\d+
}(?!(?:}})*}(?!}))  - a } char that is not escaped (there must not be a } preceded with zero or more double } chars)

The .replaceAll('{{','{').replaceAll('}}','}') part finishes the transformation.
See the JS demo:


function format(template, ...values) {
  const regex = /(?<=(?<!\{)(?:\{\{)*)\{\d+}(?!(?:}})*}(?!}))/g;
  return template.replace(regex, ([, index]) => {
    const valueIndex = parseInt(index, 10);
    if (valueIndex >= values.length) throw new Error("Not enough arguments")
    return String(values[valueIndex]).replaceAll('{{','{').replaceAll('}}','}');

  });
}

console.log([
  format("{0}", 42), // output `42`
  format("{0} {1}", 42, "bar"), // output `42 bar`
  format("{1} {1}", 42, "bar"), // output `bar bar` ({0} ignored)
  format("{{0", 42), // output `{0` (`{{` is an escaped `{`)
  format("{{{0}", 42), // output `{42` : an escaped brace and the formatted value
  format("Mix {{0}} and {0}", 42), // outputs `Mix {0} and 42`
]);

try {
  format("{0} {1}", 42); // throw error because not enough argument are passed
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}



NOTE: You need to "prep" the values passed to the functions so that the braces are escaped, i.e. just use value.replaceAll('{','{{').replaceAll('}','}}').

@trincot format("{0} {1}", 42, "b{ar") yields the expected 42 b{ar, so what is the use case you mention?

I was thinking of format("{0}", "{{"), where the replacement value would also be subjected to the brace-halving.

@trincot this is an implementation thing, all is necessary is to send them with braces escaped, or just "prep" them with .replaceAll('{','{{').replaceAll('}','}}')

Note that there is also a problem (coming from the asker's code) whereby placeholders with two or more digits do not get replaced correctly: format("{12}", 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).
